# which function is responsible to receive data in linux "usbserial" driver?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, usbserial

I went through `usb-serial.c`, which is a source file in the `usbserial` module in the Linux kernel. I would like to implement some customization in this driver, e.g., blinking LED when a communication (Tx/Rx) happens. However, I am having trouble finding the functions which are responsible for that communication. I was able to find `serial_write` but was not able to find a `serial_read`, `serial_receive`, or similar. Does anyone know about the receive data function in this driver? Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback` (from drivers/usb/serial/generic.c). I think the line in this function that has `port->read_urbs` is basically when the USB read is starting from.

So if you make your own version of that function you can put it in  `usb_serial_operations_init` in place of `usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback`

Comment: you mean read_bulk_callback and write_bulk_callback is for rx/tx

Comment: Yes, I was probably looking at wrong thing. in read_balk_callback function the line usb_submit_urb is what is doing the USB read, basically the urb is a USB transaction that is setup (at usb_fill_bulk_urb) and then submitted for execute (at sub_submit_urb)